# What is the word for a property's facade construction?

Tags: single-word-requests

My native language is Swedish and I work as a web-developer. I am currently working on a real estate website, which is written in English.

I would like to know what to call the facade or front construction of a property?

For example, if the front of the property is built with bricks, you would write:

> "*The _____ is of brick construction.*"

Comment: I think you are already there with [*facade*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/facade)

Comment: But be careful, there's quite a difference between a stone facade and structural stone wall, for example.  Caveat also applies to brick: http://www.carsondunlop.com/resources/articles/brick-houses-solid-masonry-vs-brick-veneer/

Comment: from a large real estate site har.com - Exterior Type: Brick & Wood, Stucco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"façade"** or simply **"facade"**  is the face of a building, especially the principal front that looks onto a street.  You can describe it as having **a brick façade**.

> [façade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facade) - the front of a building (figuratively, it can mean "a way of behaving or appearing that gives other people a false idea of your true feelings or situation")